# Wordpress unable to send email to office 365 email id

Tags: wordpress, plugins, smtp, office365

In my Wordpress site in contact form 7 and woocommerce email setting I use an office 365 email id but Wordpress unable to send email to this email id. I already setup SMTP with wp mail SMTP plugin, But after configuring the plugin contact form 7 is not working properly.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: What error you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Send Grid plugin here is the link for the help https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/sendgrid-wordpress/